# Opera Drop down menu hover issue

Tags: menu, hover, opera

I have just created a dropdown for my site. It works fine in all other browsers except new version of opera that is 12.02.

Webiste Url : http://www.sktechnologyworld.com/demo/anything/

Here when you mouse over on "Categories", it displays dropdown of that categories then when you hover on categories then it displays subcategories of that category. At this time there is background line remains at top of that perticular category and this same thing in all the subcategories. However when i open dragon fly in opera by pressing ctrl+shift+I then it works fine but if dragon fly is not open then it makes it weird.

Its very strange and have not face this kind of problem before. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: its a redraw bug :( for some reason your menu is not being redrawn properly. It can be related to inefficient DOM calls.

Comment: It's a CSS-driven menu so we can't blame any DOM scripting ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Opera. As it's merely a cosmetic issue with no big impact on functionality I suggest you just [report a bug to Opera Software](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/) and forget about it until it's fixed :-)

The root cause is that Opera fails to draw the background colour of the padding-top of the A elements correctly. It's mainly triggered by the padding-top:9px instruction on #CategoriesBar .nav. However, trying to work around it means adding hacks to your CSS and that makes it harder to understand and maintain - even more likely to break in future browsers. Hence reporting a bug and not trying to work around it is your best way ahead.

Here is a simplified demo you can refer to when reporting the bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/sNHbB/

Please let me know the bug reference number and I'll give it a kick for you.